# Maximum, delete and insert fastest data structure

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

The runtime to find a max element in max heap is $O(1)$. It takes $O(\log n)$ time to delete an element and $O(\log n)$ time to insert a new element in the heap.

Does there exists a data structure in which max element can be found in $o(\log n)$ and still the time to delete is $o(\log n)$ and $o(\log n)$ time to insert a new element?

$n$ denotes the number of elements.

Comment: Do you mean "... find a *max* element in a max heap..." and also, are those running-time worst-case or amortized?

Comment: A balanced BST(like AVL tree, or even RB tree) would do the trick.

Comment: @RinkeshP Complexities would not be $o(\log n)$ in a balanced BST. More like $\Theta(\log n)$ for deletion and insertion and $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ for look up.

Comment: @Nathaniel ah yes, misinterpreted the notations.

Comment: @Russel yes i mean max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create a data structure that guarantee $o(\log n)$ time for insertion AND $o(\log n)$ for maximum extraction, be it worst, amortized or average case.

The reason is that such a data structure would allow comparison sorting in $o(n \log n)$, which is theoretically not possible.

Comment: Of course, the bound can be beaten for specific kinds of keys (e.g. strings and integers).

Comment: Yes of course! If some hypotheses are made on keys, such complexities can be improved. For example, if keys are integers within known bounds, $\mathcal{O}(1)$ for insertion and deletion may be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if input numbers are labeled from 1 to $n$ then?

Comment: @Rma Using the same name $n$ for bound and for size of the structure is not wise. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15655841/9625881) for some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer, you can get $O(1)$ amortized bound for find, insert, and delete with some limitations with soft-heap [[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_heap), [original paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15859-f05/www/documents/p1012-chazelle.pdf), [simplified implementation](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611973068.53)]. This heap can break the lower-bound for sorting by allowing some kind of *corruptions* to the keys.

Corruption means the soft-heap will make changes to keys of certain items in the heap so that multiple items will *share* a common key, without any means of retrieving the original keys. The number of corrupted keys can be controlled by a paremeter $\varepsilon$ such that it is guaranteed that at most $\varepsilon n$ are corrupted. Despite this seemingly unusual implementation it has applications for MST and linear-time selection.

Answer (score -2):

Data structure that can be used for the aforementioned situation :

**AVL tree :** The self-balancing feature of AVL tree guarantees the performance of O(logN) in the worst case for all operations, including insertion, deletion, and searching.

**Disadvantage of AVL tree :** It's a complex data structure. if the program involves frequent insertion and deletion of elements then one should rather use red-black tree to avoid multiple rotations.

Comment: $O(\log n)$ is not the same as $o(\log n)$